# Swagger - Wrong Example Value

Tags: java, swagger

I have an older JAX-RS Webservice which is documented with `Swagger 1.5.12`.
To keep the webservice backwards compatible I duplicated the controller and the model and put it in two different packages.

`de.kembytes.webservice.rest.v1_0`
`de.kembytes.webservice.rest.v1_0.model`

`de.kembytes.webservice.rest.v2_0`
`de.kembytes.webservice.rest.v2_0.model`

The controllers look like this:

**Version 1.0:**

```
package de.kembytes.webservice.rest.v1_0;

import de.kembytes.webservice.rest.v1_0.model.WebserviceRequest;
import de.kembytes.webservice.rest.v1_0.model.WebserviceResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Api(value = "Webservice")
@Path("/webservice")
public class WebserviceController {
    @POST
    @Path("/calculate")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Version 1.0")
    public WebserviceResponse calculate(WebserviceRequest request){
        WebserviceResponse response = new WebserviceResponse();
        // do logic
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Version 2.0:**

```
package de.kembytes.webservice.rest.v2_0;

import de.kembytes.webservice.rest.v2_0.model.WebserviceRequest;
import de.kembytes.webservice.rest.v2_0.model.WebserviceResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Api(value = "Webservice")
@Path("/webservice/2.0")
public class WebserviceController {
    @POST
    @Path("/calculate")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Version 2.0")
    public WebserviceResponse calculate(WebserviceRequest request){
        WebserviceResponse response = new WebserviceResponse();
        // do logic
        return response;
    }
}
```

In the Swagger UI the two versions are displayed correctly.
[image: Swagger-UI]

The problem is that the example value in the Swagger UI is always generated from the `WebserviceRequest` of version 2.0.
How can I configure the example value to be generated from the request of the corresponding version?

The Swagger-Config look like this:

```
beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] {"http", "https"});
beanConfig.setBasePath(contextPath);
beanConfig.setResourcePackage("de.kembytes.webservice.rest");
beanConfig.setScan(true);
```